# Get records in Mysql where unix timestamp is today

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I'm storing records in msyql where a resolve_by column has a unix timestamp.

I'm trying this query:

```
SELECT id FROM tickets WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME('resolve_by','%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
```

The basic table structure is:

```
id|resolve_by|date_created
4, 1506092040, 1506084841
```

But this is returning 0 records.  How can I get records where the unix timestamp value = today's date?

Thanks,

Comment: can you share database basic structure with some data..??

Answer (score 4):

Changed query from :

```
SELECT id FROM tickets WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME('resolve_by','%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
```

To:

```
SELECT id FROM tickets WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(resolve_by,'%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
```

It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

In general you'll want to avoid using functions on the columns side of `where` conditions, as it will most probably disqualify your query to benefit from indexes.

Consider something like:

```
create table test_table ( id varchar(36) primary key, ts timestamp );

insert into test_table (id,ts) values('yesterday',     current_timestamp - interval 1 day);
insert into test_table (id,ts) values('midnight',      current_date);
insert into test_table (id,ts) values('now',           current_timestamp);
insert into test_table (id,ts) values('next midnight', current_date + interval 1 day);
insert into test_table (id,ts) values('tomorrow',      current_timestamp + interval 1 day);

create index test_table_i1 on test_table (ts);

select *
  from test_table
 where ts >= current_date
   and ts <  current_date + interval 1 day;
;
```

PS: you can also use

```
select *
  from test_table
 where ts between current_date and current_date + interval 1 day;
```

if you're not picky about excluding next midnight (`between` accepts both boundaries)